# 404 Page Not Found With CodeIgniter REST_Controller

Tags: rest, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to use [CodeIgniter REST_Controller](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver). Following is my code.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once (APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Test extends REST_Controller{

    public function index_get() {
        $this->response(array(''));
    }
}
```

When I access `http://codeigniter/index.php/test` the response

```
<xml><item/></xml>
```

is shown on the browser.

But when trying to access

`http://codeigniter/index.php/test.xml` or `http://codeigniter/index.php/test.html` I get a 404 error.

The documentation of the above mentioned library says that both

```
http://example.com/books.json 
http://example.com/books?format=json
```

works with the library.

Can someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How did you solve this problem finally?

Answer (score 1):

You must call it like this

SERVER-URL/index.php/test/index

And if you have the test.php inside a folder in controllers then call it like this

SERVER-URL/index.php/test/FOLDER-NAME/index

Tahir Rauf
http://www.onethatmatters.com